# Why jsfiddle is not rendering at all in IE8 and previous versions?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, rendering, jsfiddle, ie8-browser-mode

I tried to open http://jsfiddle.net/ in IE8 with `BrowserMode-- IE8` and `Document Mode--IE8` in developer tools. In other browsers it's working fine, and even in IE9 it's working fine. But I see javascript errors in `IE8 and older versions of IE`.

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier 
EditorCM.js?Spring, line 105 character 25

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' 
heyoffline.js?Spring, line 24 character 5

SCRIPT5009: 'MooShellEditor' is undefined 
jsfiddle.net, line 91 character 7

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'editor': object is null or undefined 
Actions.js?Spring, line 130 character 5
```

this is how it's rendered in `IE8`
[image]

Is jsfiddle working with IE8 and older versions?

Comment: I would recommend a domain or private webserver where you can upload HTML files for testing in IE8 -- I haven't found an online one that works (JSFiddle, JSBin, Code Pen all don't work in IE8 for me)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/311). In short:

> For all unsupported browsers (like IE8 or mobile phones) please use
>   DRAFT feature.
>
> - Log in to the service on your favourite browser.
> - Create fiddle and Run it
> - On IE8 open the http://jsfiddle.net/draft/

Comment: You can also use some alternative services like JSBin that seems to work with IE8 (until now).

Comment: To just test if your fiddle shows your problem in IE8, you could also test it by using the 'Collaboration > Share full screen result' function

Comment: A short time following this post, a message was added flatly stating that JSFiddle "does not support IE8." Realize IE8 is an archaic old browser, but some of us in corporate environs don't have any choice in the matter :(

Comment: Note that this requires you to be logged-in to JSFiddle on both browers.

Comment: @PomCompot:problem with JSBin is that most banking institutions doesn't allow access to JSBin, and they like to stick to IE..!

Answer (score 4):

Create your jsfiddle on a modern browser then when you want to test on IE8 use the full screen link.

```
Share > Share full screen result.
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but doesn't seem to work for me in IE8 on WinXP.