# replace a number with star sign javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml

How can I replace a text or number in a span element with javascript/jquery?
this is what i have tried but the console says "Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined" dont understand whats the problem, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
    function changeNumber()
{
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("grade").innerHTML; 
    var x = element.replace('1','*');
    document.getElementsByClassName("grade").innerHTML=x;
}
```

If it matters the span element i created dynamically in javascript...

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName("grade")` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), it is not like `getElementbyId`, you need to loop it.

If you just have one

```
function changeNumber()
{
    var element= document.getElementsByClassName("grade")[0];
    var text = element.innerHTML; 
    var x = text.replace('1','*');
    element.innerHTML=x;
}
```

If you have a set

```
function changeNumber()
{
    var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("grade");
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var text = element.innerHTML; 
        var x = text.replace('1','*');
        element.innerHTML=x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont understand what you mean with a set, I tried to just add more variables to it with more numbers 2, ** and so on until 5 but then it still just creates one star for number one... what do I need to put in the loop to make it change eatch number to eatch amount of stars?

Comment: Or do I really need to create 5 functions to change 5 different numbers into stars?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have jQuery included in your page, and are comfortable with it's usage, try the following code:

```
function changeNumber()
{
    $(".grade").each(function(){
        var self = this
        self.text(self.text().replace('1','*'))
    }); 
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/uUHv8/

Comment: nice, thanks! dont feel comfortable with either yet but jquery looks very promising :)

Comment: How can i add more numbers to the loop, say i want to convert numbers from 1-5 to 1-5 amount of stars?

Comment: Nothing like changing the question after everyone answered your first one. Accpt an answer and make a new question.

Comment: ok I will, but seems unnecessary when it's the same question only with more numbers and probably a small configuration, but then I'm not that good at coding either so I'll do as I'm told...

Answer (score 0):

While the posted answers are correct, and despite the fact that you've accepted an answer, I was intrigued by the possibility of creating a `replace()` function to work with a `nodeList` (or, strictly-speaking, an `Object`), so:

```
Object.prototype.replace = function (n, r) {
    var textMethod = this[0] && this[0].textContent !== undefined;
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (textMethod) {
            this[i].textContent = this[i].textContent.replace(n, r);
        } else {
            this[i].innerText = this[i].innerText.replace(n, r);
        }
    }
    return this;
};

document.getElementsByTagName('p').replace(/1/, '*');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4jKKb/3/).

I can confirm this works in Chrome 25, Firefox 19 (also 14 and 18, hadn't updated *this* computer in a while) under Win XP. I can't test in IE, since it, and JS Fiddle, [seem to be having issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260947/why-jsfiddle-is-not-rendering-at-all-in-ie8-and-older-versions).

It may, also, not be a good idea; but it seemed useful (and relatively interesting) at the point at which I put it together. Hopefully it may be of some use.